# Why does the browser " pause " when opening a link in a new tab ? What is "Profiling overhead"?

Tags: performance, caching, google-chrome-devtools

I am analyzing a performance problem when opening any link in a new tab of my application. I am using the chrome dev tools and I have seen some interesting things ( both from my application and others ).

If I make a record of the performance with the devs tools , since it opens until it is completely loaded , I get something like this :

[image: Performance recording]

In green we have the "regular" loading of the page, with its scripts, requests etc... but in red there are two things that catch my attention:

1. What is **profiling overhead**? After different tests I have been able to verify that it is lengthened depending on the total load, if the page takes 60 sec in total to be ready, the profiling overhead occupies around 15 sec, always more or less 25% of the total.
2. Why does it show as most of the time the ***"idle"*** state if the process cannot be intervened ? what does this "state" count ?

Context :

- I open new tabs , with right click-> open link in new tab.
- I start chrome with `start chrome --auto-open-devtools-for-tab`s to waste as little time as possible in the "performance" window ( without automating it yet ).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be meta computation for additional processing and resource consumption required to gather the performance insights of each metric like CPU, memory, browser reflows/repaints, js executions, etc. As part of this, the browser needs to track user events & function calls, instrument the code, network requests, rendering updates, etc. This should not happen for production cases.

I also do not know of any tools which could help to separate out this data for actual analysis. To ensure accurateness, it can be tested across other browsers like Firefox.